# Source code for mainCRTStartup() in Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Not sure if I can ask this sort of question here, but I am interested in viewing the source code for `mainCRTStartup()` in Visual C++.

Did Microsoft made this source code available?

Comment: Do you want the source of that psuedo-source debug symbols?

Comment: You can just set a breakpoint in `main` and look up the call stack. And yes the source code is available.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look in `%VSINSTALLDIR%VC\crt\src\vcruntime\`, where `%VSINSTALLDIR%` would be something like `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0` for Visual Studio 2015 for example, so different depending on which version you are on, etc. The function you are asking for is in `exe_main.cpp`

If you are running through the Visual Studio debugger, a good tip is to hit *F11*, or in the main menu bar go: *Debug* -> *Step Into*, that will start debugging and break at the top of `main`. Then you can just go up the call stack to `mainCRTStartup` and the it should be able to find the source for you.